# Pandas Python: Slice / Transform URL to get item and item counts

Tags: python, pandas

If I have column data, for example 100 entries that fall under two formats; under the column name URL:

```
http//mysportswebsite.com/shop/?Baseball+Bat=5

http//memoribilia.com/checkout?autograph=1
```

How can I extract the item and number purchased?

Ideally I would like to add new columns (if they did not exist already) for in this example Baseball Bat and autograph then add the respective count of 5 and 1 to their columns (or just add to columns if they existed from a prior example),to infer purchasing counts from this data.

I would want to do this to the entire URL column in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python already has library to parse urls.

```
>>> import urllib.parse as urlparse
>>> url = 'http//mysportswebsite.com/shop/?Baseball+Bat=5'
>>> parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> params = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
>>> print(params)
{'Baseball Bat': ['5']}
```

Answer (score 2):

for this question (which has a bit limited information) I would propose:

if your df looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"url": ["http//mysportswebsite.com/shop/?Baseball+Bat=5", "http//memoribilia.com/checkout?autograph=1"]})

                                              url
0  http//mysportswebsite.com/shop/?Baseball+Bat=5
1      http//memoribilia.com/checkout?autograph=1
```

you could do this:

```
df['product_count_tuple'] = df.url.apply(lambda x: x.split('?')[1].split('='))
df['product'] = df.product_count_tuple.apply(lambda x: x[0].replace('+', ' '))
df['count'] = df.product_count_tuple.apply(lambda x: x[1])
df = df.drop('product_count_tuple', 1)
```

which results in:

```
                                              url       product count
0  http//mysportswebsite.com/shop/?Baseball+Bat=5  Baseball Bat     5
1      http//memoribilia.com/checkout?autograph=1     autograph     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if the problem was further complicated by the fact that some URLS were like such http//memoribilia.com/checkout?autograph=1&Baseball+Bat=2&Gloves=2    So more than one item

Comment: can you update your question with how you would like the output to be in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach with `re` module:

```
import re
df['item'] = df['URL'].apply(lambda x: (re.findall('\?(.*)=', x)[0]).replace('+', ' '))
df['count'] = df['URL'].apply(lambda x: int((re.findall('=(.*)', x)[0])))
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure Python, one way to do this is by splitting the string at '?', taking the second component, and splitting again at '='.

```
url = 'http://mysportswebsite.com/shop/?Baseball+Bat=5'
item, count = url.split('?')[1].split('=')
```

You can use `apply` to run this operation over a column, however if you have a large number of URLs, it is more efficient to use the built in string methods for the same operation. The syntax is quite similar.

```
data = pd.Series([
    'http://mysportswebsite.com/shop/?Baseball+Bat=5',
    'http//memoribilia.com/checkout?autograph=1'])
df = data.str.split('?', expand=True)[1].str.split('=', expand=True)
df.columns = ['item', 'count']
```